# Syntax error near unexpected token '(' when using terminal

Tags: c, ubuntu

I am trying to get a cpuid for my tablet that is bricked and I have this code and when I execute it on ubuntu via terminal, it gives the following error:
Line 5: Syntax error near unexpected token '(' 
Line 5: 'int main(void)'

how can  I  resolve this issue?

```
#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char data[64];
    int received_length;
    int r = 1;
    libusb_context* ctx = NULL;
    libusb_device_handle* dev_handle = NULL;

    libusb_init(&ctx);
    dev_handle = libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(ctx, 0x0955, 0x7820);
    if(dev_handle)
    {
        r = libusb_bulk_transfer(dev_handle, 0x81, data, sizeof(data), &received_length, 10000);
        if (r == 0)
        {
            if(received_length == 8)
            {
               printf("uid: 0x%08X%08X\n", *((uint32_t*)data+1), *((uint32_t*)data+0));
            }
            else
            {
                r = 1;
                printf("Error: We got %d bytes of data insetad of the 8 bytes we expected...\n", received_length);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Error: USB read failed!\n");
        }
        libusb_release_interface(dev_handle, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error: Failed to open device!\n");
    }
    libusb_exit(ctx);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: Have you compiled the program? You can't run C programs directly from the shell, you have to compile it first and run the resulting executable.

Comment: I just added the error message

Comment: I get that error message if I try to run the `.c` file as if it were a shell script. It sounds like you're not compiling it.

Comment: I was able to compile the above code without modification and without any errors using `gcc -c` on Fedora 18. I agree with the assessment @Barmar gave.

Comment: OffTopic: your main() returns `r`, which indicates that you are bound for a paradigm shift.

Comment: I got compiled and it is working, ++ for your help

Comment: Suggest you accept an answer then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile the program and run the executable. If the program is in `foo.c`, you compile it with:

```
gcc foo.c -o foo
```

Then you execute it with:

```
./foo
```

You can't run a C source file directly -- C is not a scripting language.